# How can I add an incremental number to each element in a grouped series?

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number, data-partitioning, over-clause

I am facing a problem where I have a table called `Group` and a table called `Entry`. The `Group` table has a primary key `Id`. The `Entry` table has a primary key `Id`, a foreign key to the `Group` table's `Id` called `GroupId`. The `Entry` table has one more column `Weight`. This `Weight` is an integer and all it does is tell me the sort weight where zero is shown at the top.

Basically what happened is, someone made this `Weight` field nullable when the database was designed. Now I need to go through and adjust the `Weight` to fit the `UNIQUE` constraint we intend on adding: `UNQIUE(GroupId, Weight)` to the `Entry` table. This prevents two `Entry` entries from having the same sort weight when they're in the same group basically.

What query would let me go through all of our existing data and simply number the `Weight` column on each of the entries on a group by group basis from 0 to N where N is the number of `Entry` entries in a `Group`? I want to set the weight based on the `Id` of the `Entry` so that the lowest `Id` for an `Entry` in a given `Group` gets the lowest `Weight`.

I want one big ol' query that will go through the `Group` table, join up all of the `Entry` entries and then iterate through them and assign the sequence. But, I have no clue where to start on that.

Comment: [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) - SQL Server 2005+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you would use the [MS SQL Over Clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

Here is an [sqlfiddle sample to show you how to do it in one query](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9a894/1)

Hope this helps.

```
CREATE TABLE Entry (Id INT PRIMARY KEY, GroupId INT, Weight INT);

CREATE TABLE [Group] (Id INT PRIMARY KEY, Label VARCHAR(10));

INSERT [Group] (Id, Label)
VALUES(1, 'test');


INSERT Entry (Id, GroupId, Weight)
VALUES(1,1, null)

INSERT Entry (Id, GroupId, Weight)
VALUES(2,1, null)

INSERT Entry (Id, GroupId, Weight)
VALUES(3,1, null)

UPDATE E
  SET E.WEIGHT = o.WEIGHTIS
--SELECT *
FROM Entry E
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT G.Id GID, E.Id EID, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY G.Id ORDER BY E.ID) WeightIs
    FROM [Group] G
    INNER JOIN Entry E
      ON G.Id = E.GroupId  
) o
ON o.GID = E.GroupID AND o.EID = E.Id
```

Comment: Ah this helps so very much. Thank you. I have been sitting here trying to do this for ages and have never even used the `OVER` clause. That's really neat! It definitely made our tester happy :)

Comment: The PARTITION BY is the key player in this statement, it resets the numbers when the Group Id changes. :)

Comment: Yeah I was wondering if that is what it did. Upon further research it made more sense.